# CMD shell: PATH splitting onto several lines

Tags: windows, cmd, dos

I have found on a couple of web pages different ways of splitting the Windows %PATH variable onto  several lines:

```
1. for /f "delims=;" %a in ("%path%") do echo %a  . . . (doesn't work)
 2. for %G in ("%Path:;=" "%") do @echo %G
 3. for %a in ("%Path:;=";"%") do @echo %~a
 4. ECHO.%PATH:;= & ECHO.%
```

Can anyone please explain `why (1) doesn't work, and how (2), (3) and (4) do`?
And, is there a way to do it with bash-like variable semantics - i mean, with ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION ?

Comment: No 1. does not work because it seperates only the part left of the first delimitier. <br />No 2. works because it uses a substitution and to the for-command it looks like seperate keywords. However, you won't get rid of the quotes in the output <br />No 3 is basically the same as No 2 except that it strips off the quotes. <br />No 4 is the pretty cool since it basically replaces any semicolon with an echo-command so you ar actually getting n seperate echo commands, each with a different part of the path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1** `for /f` iterates over a set of lines. It can split the line into tokens, but not iterate over them

**2** and **3** - Each semicolon in the variable is replaced with a quoted delimiter (in *2* it is a space and in *3* a new semicolon) and the variable enclosed in quotes, so at the end we have

```
path       dir1;dir2;dir3
quoted    "dir1;dir2;dir3"
replacement
case 2 - "dir1" "dir2" "dir3"
case 3 - "dir1";"dir2";"dir3"
               ^ See here the replacement
```

Then a `for` command is used to iterate over a delimited (by spaces or semicolons) list of quoted elements

**4** Here the parser is used. Lines are parsed and then executed. At parse time each semicolon in the `path` variable is replaced with `& echo.`, that is, a command concatenation and a new `echo` command.  So the efect is that when the line is readed it is processed as

```
Read line

echo %path:;= &echo.%
     v..............v Variable expanded
      dir1;dir2;dir3 = dir1 & echo.dir2 & echo.dir3

Final command after parser work

echo dir1 &echo.dir2 &echo.dir3
            ^ .........^...  echo commands included in line at parse time
```

With delayed expansion active,

**1** will also not work, it has the same problem.

**2** and **3** should work the same. The only "problem" is that `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` has no effect on a command line (what you are using in the question). You will need to use a batch file or start a separate `cmd` instance with delayed expansion active

```
cmd /v /c"for %a in ("!path:;=";"!") do @echo %~a"
```

The only difference is that from a batch file (not from command line), existing exclamations inside the variable will be lost when the `@echo %%~a` is parsed.

**4** will not work. It uses the fact that the parser does normal variable expansion before the command line is processed for command handling. That way when the command is analyzed the full chain of `echo` commands can be found.

But with delayed expansion syntax, the expansion is done after the command has been parsed and what will be echoed to console is the chain of `echo` commands, not the execution of them.